# Parsing a date description to date itself

Tags: python

Need to resolve date from string where that date can be represented in several ways: 'Several seconds ago','14 minutes ago', '1 hour ago', '7 hours ago', '1 day ago', '2 days ago', '1 week ago', '3 weeks ago', '16 april 09:44', 'Today 09:44', 'Yesterday 09:44'
An attempt to solve this task led to very verbose code. Is there more concise and elegant way to parse such strings.

The code below covers only a couple of cases to show attempt. Need to cover all cases.

```
import datetime

def parse_date(item: str):
    params = item.strip().split(' ')
    # print(params)
    if len(params) == 2:
        day, time = params
        if day == 'Today':
                date = datetime.date.today()
        elif day == 'Yesterday':
                date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        else:
            print('Failed to resolve day:', item)
            return

        print(date)
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M').time()
        return datetime.datetime.combine(date=date, time=time)

    elif len(params) == 3:
        day, month_hru, time = params
        day = int(day)
        months_map = {
            'January': 1,
            'February ': 2,
            'March': 3,
            'April': 4,
            'May': 5,
            'June': 6,
            'July': 7,
            'August': 8,
            'September': 9,
            'October': 10,
            'November': 11,
            'December': 12,
        }
        month = months_map.get(month_hru)
        if not month:
            print('Failed to resolve month:', item)
            return

        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')
        print(month, day)
        return datetime.datetime(day=day, month=month, year=today.year, hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute)

    else:
        print('Failed to resolve date', item)
        return

parse_date("14 January 09:44")
parse_date("Yesterday 09:44")
```

Comment: What would "Several seconds ago" be parsed to?

Comment: Something like that is implemented in [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way of generalizing what you want because it's not a general problem. You're going to have to identify which pattern an input string belongs to, and parse it according to the logic for that pattern. Split it up into different helper functions that handle each case if you think it's hard to read a long function. For each of these functions, I'm going to add an optional argument "now" to calculate the time assuming `now` is a fixed time to help with debugging.

You need to handle the following formats, and we'll define a function for each of them

| Format | Function |
| --- | --- |
| 'Several seconds ago' | `parse_ago()` |
| '14 minutes ago' '1 hour ago', '7 hours ago', '1 day ago', '2 days ago', '1 week ago', '3 weeks ago' | `parse_ago()` |
| '16 april 09:44' | `parse_abs()` |
| 'Today 09:44', 'Yesterday 09:44' | `parse_rel()` |

---

It's unclear how many seconds are "several" in "several seconds ago", so I'm going to assume 5

To parse the `X <min/hr/day/week> ago` pattern, we can use a regular expression.

`(\d+|several) (second|minute|hour|day|week)s? ago` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ntOa8E/2)

Explanation:

- `(\d+|several)`: One or more digits, or the word `"several"`. Also capture these in a group
- `(second|minute|hour|day|week)s?`: Any one of those strings specifying the quantity of time, followed by an optional `s`.
- `ago`: Literally a space and then the characters `ago`

Once we extract the number and the quantity, we can create a dictionary and pass that as kwargs to `datetime.timedelta()` to get a `timedelta`. Adding this to `now` gives us the time we want.

```
import re

def parse_ago(inp, now=None):
    if not now: now = datetime.datetime.now()
    inp = inp.lower()
    rex = r"(\d+|several) (second|minute|hour|day|week)s? ago"
    result = re.findall(rex, inp)
    if result:
        try:
            num = float(result[0][0])
        except ValueError:
            num = 5
            
        qty = result[0][1]
        tdelta = datetime.timedelta(**{qty + "s": float(num)})
        return now - tdelta
    return None
```

---

Next, let's tackle the "Today" and "Yesterday" cases. Finding the time using a regex is fairly easy.

`(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CUB7D0/1)

Explanation:

- `(\d{1,2})`: One or two digits
- `:` : Literally a colon
- `(\d{2})`: Two digits

Now that we know the time, all we need to do is combine this with "today"/"yesterday"/"tomorrow".

```
def parse_rel(inp, now=None):
    if now: today = now.date()
    else: today = datetime.date.today()
    
    inp = inp.lower()
    rex_time = r"(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})"
    timestamp = re.findall(rex_time, inp)
    if not timestamp: tm = datetime.time(hour=0)
    else: tm = datetime.time(hour=int(timestamp[0][0]), minute=int(timestamp[0][1]))
    
    if "today" in inp:
        return datetime.datetime.combine(today, tm)
    
    if "yesterday" in inp:
        return datetime.datetime.combine(today + datetime.timedelta(days=-1), tm)

    if "tomorrow" in inp:
        return datetime.datetime.combine(today + datetime.timedelta(days=1), tm)

    return None
```

---

And finally, let's do the absolute date format. For this, we'll define a `monthlookup` dictionary to get the month number from the name because it's the easiest, although there are other ways to do this. We can parse the date and time separately -- date using the following regex, and time using the same one we used previously.

`(\d{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]+) (\d{4})?` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2s0EPf/1)

Explanation:

- `(\d{1,2})`: One or two digits for day
- `([a-zA-Z]+)`: Any number of characters for month
- `(\d{4})?`: Optionally, four digits for year

The separately parsed date and time are later combined.

```
def parse_abs(inp, now=None):
    if not now: now = datetime.datetime.now()
        
    monthlookup = { 'january': 1, 'february ': 2, 'march': 3, 'april': 4, 'may': 5, 'june': 6, 'july': 7, 'august': 8, 'september': 9, 'october': 10, 'november': 11, 'december': 12}
    inp = inp.lower()
    rex_date = r"(\d{1,2}) ([a-zA-Z]+) (\d{4})?"
    rex_time = r"(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})"
    dt = re.findall(rex_date, inp)
    tm = re.findall(rex_time, inp)
    if not tm: tdelta = datetime.time(hour=0)
    else: tdelta = datetime.time(hour=int(tm[0][0]), minute=int(tm[0][1]))

    if not dt: return None# Or maybe? basedate = datetime.date.today()
    else: 
        if len(dt[0]) == 3 and dt[0][2]:
            # Year specified
            yr = int(dt[0][2])
        else:
            yr = now.year
        basedate = datetime.date(yr, monthlookup[dt[0][1]], int(dt[0][0]))
    
    return datetime.datetime.combine(basedate, tdelta)
```

---

Now, let's combine all of these functions in a single wrapper:

```
def parse_descriptive_datetime(inp, now=None):
    if not now: now = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    inp = inp.lower()
    
    if inp == "now":
        return now
    
    if "ago" in inp:
        return parse_ago(inp, now)
    
    if "today" in inp or "tomorrow" in inp or "yesterday" in inp:
        return parse_rel(inp, now)
    
    return parse_abs(inp, now)
```

To test our functions, let's define a list of tests, and use a single base datetime.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
tests = ["Now", 'Several seconds ago','14 minutes ago', '1 hour ago', '7 hours ago', '1 day ago', '2 days ago', '1 week ago', '3 weeks ago', '16 april 09:44', '16 April 2021 09:44', 'Today 09:44', 'Yesterday 09:44', "Tomorrow 09:44"]
for t in tests:
    print(t, ":", parse_descriptive_datetime(t, now))
```

which gives the output:

```
Now : 2021-05-14 15:58:03.968794
Several seconds ago : 2021-05-14 15:57:58.968794
14 minutes ago : 2021-05-14 15:44:03.968794
1 hour ago : 2021-05-14 14:58:03.968794
7 hours ago : 2021-05-14 08:58:03.968794
1 day ago : 2021-05-13 15:58:03.968794
2 days ago : 2021-05-12 15:58:03.968794
1 week ago : 2021-05-07 15:58:03.968794
3 weeks ago : 2021-04-23 15:58:03.968794
16 april 09:44 : 2021-04-16 09:44:00
16 April 2021 09:44 : 2021-04-16 09:44:00
Today 09:44 : 2021-05-14 09:44:00
Yesterday 09:44 : 2021-05-13 09:44:00
Tomorrow 09:44 : 2021-05-15 09:44:00
```

Comment: Regular expressions rock!